# Python script for starting my printer is failing

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to print a document using the following Python script. At the end of the document, it says that it is successful but it is not.  The printer won't start even though the code runs without throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import win32print
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def print_document_remote(file_path, printer_ip):
    try:
        # Open the file in binary mode

        with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
            content = file.read()

        # Open the printer
        printer_name = fr"{printer_ip}"
        printer = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

        try:
            # Start a print job
            job_info = win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer, 1, ("Print Job", None, "RAW"))

            try:
                # Start a new page
                win32print.StartPagePrinter(printer)

                # Write the content to the printer
                win32print.WritePrinter(printer, content)

                # End the current page
                win32print.EndPagePrinter(printer)

                # End the print job
                win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer)
                print("Printing success!")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Failed to print:", str(e))

        finally:
            # Close the print job
            win32print.ClosePrinter(printer)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to start print job:", str(e))


file_path = r"FILEPATH"  # Local path to the document to print
printer_ip = "THE NAME OF MY COMPUTER" # IP address of the printer

print_document_remote(file_path, printer_ip)
```

I have tried using the name of my computer as the printer IP as well as the actual ip_adress. The script throws an error when I use the IP address but it seems to work without error when I use the name of my computer.